# Fix file format with QFileDialog.getSaveFileName in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, file-format, qfiledialog

I am creating an app with PyQt5. It opens a web-browser and it should allow the user to download files.

It looks like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui,QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtWebChannel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


def _downloadRequested(item): # QWebEngineDownloadItem
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    #
    global pathsave_custom
    pathsave_custom = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, "Select destination folder and file name", "", "Zip files (*.zip)",
                                options=options)[0]
    print('downloading to', item.path())
    item.setPath(pathsave_custom)
    print('downloading to', item.path())
    print(item)
    print(type(item))
    item.accept()



app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w=QWebEngineView()
w.page().fullScreenRequested.connect(QWebEngineFullScreenRequest.accept)
w.load(QtCore.QUrl('https://google.com'))
w.page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(_downloadRequested)
w.showMaximized()
app.exec_()
```

I would like to impose the format of the downloaded file. No matter what the user writes, there should be an extension chosen by me at the end of the downloaded file. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Why not just check to see if it's there, and if not, add it?

Comment: What do you mean? I want to give the possibility to download new files.

Comment: Check if the chosen filename has the required extension, and if not add it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanna do. How?

Comment: Are you kidding?
1) I didn't know the command "endswith".
2) I want to impose the extension with QfileDialog. How do I integrate that command with QFileDialog?

If I were able to solve the problem myself, why should I have asked the question?

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I changed this line:

```
 item.setPath(pathsave_custom)
```

with:

```
item.setPath(pathsave_custom + '.zip')
```

Whatever the user writes, the downloaded file is a ZIP.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you seem to always add `.zip` extension even if the user already put `.zip.

You can do the following and add `.zip` if there is no extension or the extension is not `zip`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui,QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtWebChannel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

def _downloadRequested(item): # QWebEngineDownloadItem
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    #
    global pathsave_custom
    pathsave_custom = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, "Select destination folder and file name", "", "Zip files (*.zip)",
                                options=options)[0]

    if not file_extension or file_extension != '.zip':
        pathsave_custom = pathsave_custom + '.zip'
        
    print('downloading to', item.path())
    item.setPath(pathsave_custom)
    print('downloading to', item.path())
    print(item)
    print(type(item))
    item.accept()
```